# async and await not working in asp.net MVC

Tags: async-await

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> Save(List<SalesNewItemModel> aSalesNewItemModel)
    {
        string msg =  await _aSalesNewItemManager.Save(aSalesNewItemModel);
        return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Shows Error type string is not awaitable

Comment: You can not apply async await to every thing. Return type of _aSalesNewItemManager.Save(aSalesNewItemModel) must be a task.

Comment: Can u please retype my function

Comment: I need this method to provide any help _aSalesNewItemManager.Save(aSalesNewItemModel)

Comment: [async await docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)  ..[Relevant Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the method doesn't call anything async, just make it non-async.

```
public JsonResult Save(List<SalesNewItemModel> aSalesNewItemModel)
{
    string msg = _aSalesNewItemManager.Save(aSalesNewItemModel);
    return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Or you should change `_aSalesNewItemManager.Save` to return `Task<string>` and make use of asynchronous processing in that method. For example async IO.